# esbuild timeout when codesplitting

Tags: ruby-on-rails, esbuild

Using esbuild with a Rails 7 app, I've been successful in code splitting 2 packages: one with the StimulusJS controllers and another with a ReactJS app. The configuration works fine in development.

When pushed to the CI (GitHub Actions) or pushed directly to Heroku, it times out.

###### package.json

```
  "scripts": {
    "build": "node app/assets/config/esbuild.js",
    "build:css": "sass ./app/assets/stylesheets/application.sass.scss ./app/assets/builds/application.css --no-source-map --load-path=node_modules"
  }
```

###### app/assets/config/esbuild.js

```js
const path = require('path');

require("esbuild").build({
  entryPoints: ["stimulus.js","article.js"],
  bundle: true,
  minify: true,
  outdir: path.join(process.cwd(), "app/assets/builds"),
  absWorkingDir: path.join(process.cwd(), "app/javascript"),
  watch: true,
  loader: { '.js': 'jsx' },
  publicPath: 'assets',
  target: 'es6',
  // custom plugins will be inserted is this array
  plugins: [],
}).catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

##### GitHub Actions

```
yarn install v1.22.19
[1/4] Resolving packages...
success Already up-to-date.
Done in 0.13s.
yarn run v1.22.19
$ node app/assets/config/esbuild.js
Error: The operation was canceled.
```

##### Heroku

Hangs on this step

```
remote:        $ node app/assets/config/esbuild.js
```

Answer (score 1):

The solution was to remove `watch: true`

```js
const path = require('path');

require("esbuild").build({
  entryPoints: ["stimulus.js","article.js"],
  bundle: true,
  minify: true,
  outdir: path.join(process.cwd(), "app/assets/builds"),
  absWorkingDir: path.join(process.cwd(), "app/javascript"),
  watch: false,  // set to true in dev
  loader: { '.js': 'jsx' },
  publicPath: 'assets',
  target: 'es6',
  // custom plugins will be inserted is this array
  plugins: [],
}).catch(() => process.exit(1));
```

**Update**

For other people who are struggling with this, please see the updated solution and discussion on the [project](https://github.com/evanw/esbuild/issues/2637).

```js
const path = require('path');

console.log("NODE_ENV: " + process.env.NODE_ENV);
console.log("CI: " + process.env.CI);
console.log(!(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || process.env.CI));

require("esbuild").build({
  entryPoints: ["stimulus.js","article.js"],
  bundle: true,
  minify: true,
  outdir: path.join(process.cwd(), "app/assets/builds"),
  absWorkingDir: path.join(process.cwd(), "app/javascript"),
  watch: !(process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production' || process.env.CI),
  loader: { '.js': 'jsx' },
  publicPath: 'assets',
  target: 'es6',
  // custom plugins will be inserted is this array
  plugins: [],
}).catch(() => process.exit(1));
```